# How to print lines which are just before a line having a pattern?

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I wanted to print a line having a pattern and the line which is just before it.
Eg: say the file is:

```
This is line 1  
This is line 2  
This is FORMAT line 3  
This is line 4  
This is line 5  
This is FORMAT line 6
```

say the pattern i want to search is `FORMAT`. So the output should be

```
This is line 2  
This FORMAT line 3  
This is line 5
This is FORMAT line 6.
```

I tried using `sed`, i was able to print the line with pattern but not the previous line.

2nd question (as do not want to create a separate question) How to print lines which do not have a particular pattern in their next lines?
for eg. for above file and pattern, output should be

```
This is line 1    
This is line 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with grep. Grep's B option can show n lines before.

```
grep -B 1 reg.ex filename
```

Comment: will it print 1 line below or above or both.

Comment: The -C option will print above & below.  The -A option will print after the match.  The -B option will print before the match.

Comment: Thanks i think it will do.

Comment: what if i want to print only those lines whose next line does not contain a pattern. I think this is exactly opposite of the above question?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.
So if the lines are 
ABC
DEF
GHI
and your pattern is DEF, you only want ABC and GHI?

Comment: I mean, in the above example output should be : 
This is line 1  
This is line 4
 as these are the only lines which do not have FORMAT in their next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/FORMAT/{H;g;p;};h' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want actually want it in awk you can do something like this:

```
$ awk '/FORMAT/ { print lastline; print } { lastline = $0 }' < format.txt
```

Comment: Or `{ print lastline RS $0 }`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '$!N;/\n.*FORMAT/p;D' file
```

This always reads 2 lines at a time and if the second line contains the pattern prints them both.